# How to determine whether the app is returning from being dormant or tombstone?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

guys, now I'm developing a windows phone 8 app, I have an issue which is how to determine whether the app is returning from being dormant or tombstone ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app should check the IsApplicationInstancePreserved property of the event args to determine whether it is returning from being dormant or tombstoned. If IsApplicationInstancePreserved is true, then your app was dormant and state was automatically preserved by the operating system. If it is false, then your app was tombstoned and should use the state dictionary to restore application state.

This is the code for details

```
private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
{
     // Determine whether it is returning from being dormant or tombstoned.
     // If it is false, return from tombstoned.
     if (e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved == false)
         //TODO
     else
         //TODO
 }
```

Wish this can help you.

Comment: A [reference to this information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: There is also this nice little `!` operator to check for `false`.

Answer (score 0):

**Dormant**

When the user navigates forward, away from an app, after the Deactivated event is raised, the operating system will attempt to put the app into a dormant state. In this state, all of the application’s threads are stopped and no processing takes place, but the application remains intact in memory. If the app is reactivated from the dormant, it doesn’t need to do anything to re-establish state, because it has been preserved.

If new apps are launched after an app has been made dormant, and these applications requires more memory than is available to provide a good user experience, the operating system will begin to tombstone dormant applications to free up memory.

**Tombstoned**

A tombstoned app has been terminated, but the operating system preserves information about its navigation state and also preserves the state dictionaries the app populated during Deactivated. The device will maintain tombstoning information for up to five apps at a time. If an app is tombstoned and the user navigates back to the application, it will be relaunched and the application can use the preserved data to restore state.

[follow the link below for detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: So how does "citing" the documentation answer the question?